# how to call postgresql stored procedure in laravel 5

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5

I have tested with two types
1)

```
 DB::statement('call abc_cmw("$ipaddress","$cname","$recvd_date","$language","$address1","$address2","$address3","$pincode","$mobileno","$amobileno","$email_address","$idproofdetail","$Description","$remedies","$gretype","$fcount","$content1","$content2","$district_problem","$city_problem", "$block_problem","$village_problem","$username","$sugg_demand","$dept_name","$indiv_grp","$ac_problem")');
```

2)

```
DB::select('exec abc_cmw("$ipaddress","$cname","$recvd_date","$language","$address1","$address2","$address3","$pincode","$mobileno","$amobileno","$email_address","$idproofdetail","$Description","$remedies","$gretype","$fcount","$content1","$content2","$district_problem","$city_problem", "$block_problem","$village_problem","$username","$sugg_demand","$dept_name","$indiv_grp","$ac_problem")');
```

but both ways have same error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax
>   error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "call" LINE 1: call
>   abc_cmw("$ipaddress","$cname","$re... ^ (SQL:
>   call
>   abc_cmw("$ipaddress","$cname","$recvd_date","$language","$address1","$address2","$address3","$pincode","$mobileno","$amobileno","$email_address","$idproofdetail","$Description","$remedies","$gretype","$fcount","$content1","$content2","$district_problem","$city_problem",
>   "$block_problem","$village_problem","$username","$sugg_demand","$dept_name","$indiv_grp","$ac_problem"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL functions are called using `SELECT` clause, e.g.:  `SELECT func()`

You should avoid inserting SQL parameters directly because of the possibility of SQL injections. Use bindings instead:

```
DB::statement('SELECT abc_cmw(?, ?, ?)', [$param1, $param2, $param3]);
```

or

```
DB::statement('SELECT abc_cmw(:param1, :param2, :param3)', [
  'param1' => $param1, 
  'param2' => $param2, 
  'param3' => $param3
]);
```

Comment: i want to know in your solution question mark replace with column name or i need to instert question mark for every column?

Comment: You can use either named bindings (second example) or array bindings (first example). If you prefer array bindings, then insert question mark for every column.

Comment: By the way, variables that are passed to functions are called parameters or arguments, not columns.

Comment: its giving me error SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: malformed array literal: ""
DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. (SQL: SELECT abc_cmw(, cdssfsdf, 2017-10-04, ,dfsfsdfsd,,,,8888888888,,abc@gmail.com,,dfsdfsfsfs,,N,1,,,58,001,,,,G,ADR,G,03))

Comment: Does your function accept an array as one of the parameters? If so, then I have bad news. Laravel doesn't support passing php array as a parameter of Postgres function. The only way around is to do it manually. Google "php pass array to postgres function"

Comment: how can i check that function accept an array as one of the parameters because db is not designed by me

Comment: is there any way to change that functions ?